# convergence of a integral using comparation

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> analyze the comparison criterion if the integral converges or not
>
> $\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{2+e^{x^3}}dx$

attempt

i used the fact that $-\frac{1}{2+e^{x^3}}\le\frac{\cos x}{2+e^{x^3}}\le\frac{1}{2+e^{x^3}}$ to get that

$-\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2+e^{x^3}}dx\le\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{2+e^{x^3}}dx\le \int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2+e^{x^3}}dx$

then for $x>1$ we have that $e^{x^3}>e^{x}\Rightarrow2+e^{x^3}>e^x$ and then $\frac{1}{2+e^{x^3}}<\frac{1}{e^x}=e^{-x}$

and then

$\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2+e^{x^3}}dx<\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}e^{-x}dx=-e^{-x}\bigg|_{2}^{+\infty}=e^{-2}$

wich mean that $\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{2+e^{x^3}}dx$ converge

did my work are correct? has a better way to conclude this?

Comment: Right ideas, but you really can't write down $\int\limits_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{2+e^{x^3}}dx$ as if were a number *until* you've shown it converges - which is what the problem is all about. A good way to proceed here is to deal with $|\cos x/(2+e^{x^3})|.$ If the integral of that is finite, i.e., absolutely convergent, then the original integral converges.

Comment: You are doing fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $\int_{0}^{y}\cos x\,dx $ is bounded and $\frac{1}{2+e^{x^3}}$ is a positive decreasing function whose limit when $x\to +\infty$ is zero, hence the integral is converging by [Dirichlet's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), for instance.